# how to find students Bydate (findByDate)

Tags: java, spring

I went to develop an application to manage students in a university, I am looking for how to find students in relation to a date entered for that I have developed the following code lines:

1- Model student.java
package com.avatar.model;

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Students")
public class Student{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private String numTel;
    private String mail;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateCurrent;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
                })

    @JoinTable(name = "student_techno",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "student_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "techno_id") })

    private Set<Techno> techno =  new HashSet<>();

      public Student() {

        }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Student(String nom, String prenom,String numTel, String mail,  Date dateCurrent,
            ) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.numTel = numTel;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.dateCurrent = dateCurrent;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public String getNumTel() {
        return numTel;
    }

    public void setNumTel(String numTel) {
        this.numTel = numTel;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getdateCurrent() {
        return dateCurrent;
    }

    public void setdateCurrent(Date dateCurrent) {
        this.dateCurrent = dateCurrent;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student[nom=" + nom + ", prenom=" + prenom + ", numTel=" + numTel + ", mail="
                + mail + ", dateCurrent=" + dateCurrent+ "]";
    }
}
```

2- Controller

```
package com.avatar.web;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.avatar.dao.StudentDao;
import com.avatar.model.Student;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/avatar")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    StudentDao studentdao;
    @GetMapping(value = "/all-students")
    public List<Student> listeDesStudent() {

        List<Student> students= studentdao.findAll();

        if (students.isEmpty())
            throw new ProductNotFoundException("No student is registered in the database");

        return students;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/all-students/dateCurrent/{dateCurrent}")
    public List<Student> viewStudent(@PathVariable("dateCurrent") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date dateCurrent) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(dateCurrent);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        dateCurrent = c.getTime();
    return studentdao.findByDate(dateCurrent);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/all-students /techno/{nomTechno}")
    List<Student >  viewStudent(@PathVariable("nomTechno") String nomTechno) {

        return studentdao.findDistinctByTechnoNomTechno(nomTechno);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/add-student")
    public Student addStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {

        Student studentAdded= studentdao.save(Student);
        return studentAdded;

    }
}
```

3- DAO

```
package com.avatar.dao;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.avatar.model.Student;

@Repository
public interface StudentDao extends JpaRepository<Student, String> {

    List<Student> findByDate(Date dateCurrent);

    List<> findDistinctByTechnoNomTechno(String nomTechno);

}
```

4- applications.properties

```
server.port= 8080

# MySQL Properties

spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/avatar?serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=*****

# Hibernate Properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

in my console i have:

```
Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.avatar.dao.StudentDao.findByDate(java.util.Date)! No property date found for type Student!
```

Comment: there's no date column in student table, I'm missing the query, but I guess you have a dateCurrent field instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update DAO  as per for below mentioned changes
If the field name is dateCurrent  then findByDateCurrent.

```java
package com.avatar.dao;
import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.List; 
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository; 
import com.avatar.model.Student; 

@Repository 
public interface StudentDao extends JpaRepository<Student, String> { 
    List<Student> findByDateCurrent(Date dateCurrent); 
    List<> findDistinctByTechnoNomTechno(String nomTechno); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing field name,  in Entity class it is not the date by dateCurrent,  thus your JPA should be findByDateCurrent